# Character escaping rules for $form_state['redirect']

Tags: 7, forms, uri

I'm writing a redirect for the form submit function, the redirect part looks like this

```
$form_state['redirect'] = array(
// $path
'catalog/search',
// $options
array('query' => array("circle_op=<&a%5Bvalue%5D=28&a%5Bl%5D" => $location, 'p' => $keyword,)),
// $http_response_code
    302,
  );
```

The problem is that the `"circle_op=<&a%5Bvalue%5D=28&a%5Bl%5D"` part on redirect transforms into `"%253Ccircle_op%3D<%26a%255Bvalue%255D%3D28%26a%255Bl%255D%3D"` inside URL.

Please explain, how to pass this key value correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule for query strings is pretty simple; you need a key, and a value. The format for this key/value pair is:

```
key=value
```

Both the key and the value will be URL encoded, so any special characters are escaped.

Take the `=` sign for example. Your sample code above uses:

`circle_op=<&a%5Bvalue%5D=28&a%5Bl%50`

as a key, and a value from the variable `$location` as a value. So without being escaped, your query string looks like this:

```
?circle_op=<&a%5Bvalue%5D=28&a%5Bl%5D=VALUE_OF_LOCATION_VAR
```

Obviously if a browser was to encounter that URL it wouldn't know what to do; there are two equal signs, so it doesn't know what is supposed to be the key, and what is supposed to be the value. It can make a guess but that's not the point.

The URL that you are redirecting to is absolutely the correct one for the input you've given for your redirect URL.

Comment: Thanks Clive! After changing the query into 

`'query' => array('circle_op' => '<', 'a[value]' => '28', 'a[l]' => $location, 'p' => $keyword,)` 

the target url is correct